# Go SSL Listener

Tags: rest, api, go, service, backend

I'm building a rest API in Go. 
I have an SSL domain and one dedicated server.

The domain points to my dedicated and works fine (https://www.myweb.com).

The error is when I'm making a request to some EndPoint of my API I do never get a response from the server.

```
func main() {
    router := NewRouter()

    handler := cors.New(cors.Options{
        AllowedMethods:   []string{"GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH"},
        AllowCredentials: true,
        AllowedOrigins:   []string{"*"},
        AllowedHeaders:   []string{"Authorization", "Content-Type", "Access-Control-Allow-Request-Method"},
    }).Handler(router)


    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServeTLS(":4433", "tls.crt", "tls.key", handler))

}
```

routes.go:

```
var routes = Routes{    Route{"Index", "GET", "/", Index}, }
func NewRouter() *mux.Router {
    fmt.Println("[INFO] Loading EndPoints...")
    router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    for _, route := range routes {
        router.
            Methods(route.Method).
            Path(endPoint + route.Pattern).
            Name(route.Name).
            Handler(route.HandlerFunc).Headers()

    }
    fmt.Println("[INFO] EndPoints loaded successfully...")

    return router
}
```

Index function

```
func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    fmt.Println("API IS RIGHT HERE latest")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    w.Header().Add("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains")
    w.Write([]byte("This is an example server.\n"))

}
```

The problem is that I can see 'API IS RIGHT HERE latest' in the console but nothing else. I mean, the response is not loading. This is the POSTMAN message
[image]

**UPDATE**

I just noticed that If I use the link and join over Firefox browser then the response works okay. But if I request the same URL from POSTMAN then I don't get a response.

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

I just disabled SSL Verification from POSTMAN and now works fine. But I wanna know what really means this option? Because I bought an SSL Certificate (It's not a self-signed)

[image]

Comment: From [document](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ResponseWriter): Changing the header map after a call to `WriteHeader` (or `Write`) has no effect unless the modified headers are trailers. I don't know if that is the root problem but you shall change the order of  `w.WriteHeader` and `w.Header().Add`.

Comment: In the code shown, you never actually add your routes to the router.

Comment: @Adrian Yes I do. I just edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

I just disabled the SSL Verification in Chrome and the response works. But I wannt know why I had to do this? It's not a self-signed certificate. I bought this one.